# Convert wchar_t to wstring in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have the following code.

```
wchar_t path[MAX_PATH +1] = {0};

SHGetFolderPathW(NULL, CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, path);
```

Here I take the program data folder path to "path" which is wchar_t. I want to convert it to wstirng and print it. How can I do that ?

Comment: `wstring(path)` O_O ?

Comment: I did it. I did the following
    std::wstring winDir(path);

then,

    cout << winDir.c_str() << endl;

But it prints only a memory address. :(

Comment: @Zarco Why the `c_str()`? And you need `std::wcout` for a `std::wstring`.

Comment: @Zarco, it's because `std::cout` expects `char*` or `std::string`, but you passing `wchar_t*`. Use `std::wcout`. No `c_str()` method needed. Also you can avoid bothering with C-strings at all in your code snippet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should not need to create a `std::wstring` for this:

```
wchar_t path[MAX_PATH +1] = {0};

SHGetFolderPathW(NULL, CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, path);

std::wcout << path;
```

Comment: @Abyx Why? It's unrelated to the OP's question as it stands. It might be a nice add-on, but it's not necessary. For all we know, the OP could be doing it in their case and only have omitted it from the question for brevity.

Comment: just for completeness

Answer (score 6):

Try the following

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  wchar_t path[MAX_PATH +1] = ...;
  std::wstring s(path);
  std::wcout << s;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you're missing a second colon in std:wcout?

Comment: @Krenair indeed, fixed.

Comment: i don't know why but it's change my wstring font?

Answer (score 3):

C++11 solution (underlying storage are guaranteed to be contiguous array):

```
std::wstring path;
path.resize(MAX_PATH +1);
SHGetFolderPathW(NULL, CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, &path[0]);
path.shrink_to_fit();
```